# Dedicated Unreal Engine Server with custom matchmaking

Tags: api, unreal-engine4, multiplayer

Please tell me if it is possible to use a dedicated server for real-time network game together with a third-party mactmaking server?

The idea is to make a backend server on Golang (matchmaking, leaderboards, lootboxes, etc.), and use the UE Server only for the game session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

This is a common approach to handling Multiplayer games in general and Unreal Engine is no exception.

Some third party solutions include [Amazon AWS Gamelift](https://aws.amazon.com/gamelift/) and [Microsoft Playfab](https://playfab.com/)

Epic Games is also working on their own Matchmaking Solution called [EOS](https://dev.epicgames.com/en-US/services)